# kcov is running as expected exept that it never finishes

Tags: rust, code-coverage, kcov

Hi I want to calculate my coverage using kcov (for rust) but when I run the following:

`kcov target/cov target/debug/foo-9685a754b64cd612`

Kcov right the result in target/cov but it never return and 
I am having to kill the prosses with signal segfault (C-c is not working for some reason).

this behaviour only happens with my project to; I cloned another project and it finishes correctly.

How do i stop this madness?

Comment: We're lacking some information, there. I guess that some of your test is in fault: does your `cargo test` hang also?

Comment: no my test is just an assert_eq(true, true) to test coverage and cargo test execute fine

Comment: I don't see what we can do to help you.

Comment: thank you for trying at least

Comment: _no my test is just an assert_eq(true, true)_ Just a guess:  do you use `export RUSTFLAGS='-C link-dead-code'`  maybe it can't find any code to check coverage ( you need to set this flag before `cargo test`)

Comment: @ÖmerErden i did not but now (`RUSTFLAGS='-C link-dead-code' cargo test --no-run`) it doesn't even run the test

Comment: Please follow: https://pastebin.com/Qr9FXvGr

Comment: I'm sorry but it did not change the outcome (i checked several times that the variable is set correctly) kcov is never running the test when rustflags='-C link-dead-code' is set